# the java tutorial web start sample not working

Tags: java

When running web start samples, I got the following error message:

> CouldNotLoadArgumentException[URL:
>   C:\Users\s9\AppData\Local\Temp\nsd3E1.tmp\ContainedTemp\javaws2]  at
>   com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

It seems to occur after I installed jre8u11。It works fine on my computer which installed jre7u67 and jre8u5 but not fine with my other computer which installed jre8u11 and jre8u20. 
Actually it has the same error with other web start program. 
I search the internet not found any thing stated with this error. 
Any Help? or I should ask this question in other place?
Thank you

plin0325

Comment: Would not recommend using jre8 yet too new, bound to be buggy.

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example with the minimal project code and the problematic JNLP file.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your jre to a previos verision to see if that is why it doesnt work.  If it continues to not work see what other factors are different from your computers that it works on succesfully.

Comment: I downgrad jre to 8u5, it works fine. But if I downgrad it to have only jre7u67, it gets the same error. I tried to my other computer,it works fine with jre7u67. I reinstorall jre8u5 to this computer, it works fine.  It seems that this particular computer need jre8u5. What are the possible factors?